# automatic get server temperature via HP iLO

Tags: hp, physical-environment, ilo

I have a couple of HP servers in 2 offices. They have iLO interfaces and i can read the temperature from there.
How can i read this temperature automaticaly over the network ? does iLO have any sort of API ??

best regards.

Comment: windows based machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HP makes a lot of software available for managing their servers, you just have to look a bit for it. They used to have a page where all of their Linux software was in one place, but they seem to have rearranged their site a bit. I found the software by going to their support site and drilling down to the server model I was looking for (though most of the software you're looking for will work on any ProLiant server, which I'm assuming you have).

1. Go to their [software and drivers](http://welcome.hp.com/country/us/en/support.html?pageDisplay=drivers) download page.
2. Click on Servers.
3. Click on ProLiant/tc Series Servers.
4. Drill down to your series (DL/ML/etc.), model (360/380/etc.) and generation (G3/G4/etc.).
5. Click on the OS closest to what you have. For Ubuntu, choose Debian. For CentOS, choose RedHat.

You'll see tons of software. Most of it was probably included on one or more CDs that came with the server if you bought it new. At my company, we use *HP System Health Application and Insight Management Agents*, also known as `hpasm`. It provides agents that can poke the hardware sensors directly, so we can see things like temperature, fan status, power supplies, and disk failures from inside the OS. It's integrated into Net-SNMP (or Windows SNMP) as a subagent, which we monitor with Nagios. On Linux, it's just an RPM/DEB package you install.

To control the iLO directly over the network, look on the software page for *HP Lights-Out Configuration Utility*. I've never used it, so I don't know what level of control it gives you, but this is the only software I'm aware of for remotely controlling the iLO. Short of that, there is also an XML interface that you can access locally on the same server that the iLO is in.

Comment: i've tryed all of these. but i need to read hardware status (temperature) only via the iLO interface some way or another. i can not curl the url and then parse the web page since it's ssl encoded and access protected.

Comment: Have you tried the Telnet/SSH interface? The basic command is `show /system1/sensorX` where `X` is some sensor number. On a DL580 G5 with iLO2, there are 13 sensors. The first four show the presence (or absence) of the CPUs themselves, and 5 through 13 are various temperature sensors. The SSH server appears to support command mode, so to get sensor 5 you could do `ssh Administrator@ilo-address show /system1/sensor5` and the command output would end up in your shell's standard output. If you prefer Telnet, take a look at Perl's Net::Telnet to screen-scrape a telnet session.

Comment: sounds great James, i'll try this out ;)

Comment: i thought i would be easier, still haven't manage to get Net::Telnet working.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you enable Telnet in the iLO? On the ones I have, SSH is enabled by default, but Telnet is not.

Comment: :)) telnet enabled. ;)

Comment: For anyone finding this via Google (like me). HP has since split out their server stuff in to a new division (HPE). Try searching from https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/?language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

Spent quite a bit of time trying to find "HP System Health Application and Insight Management Agents" so I thought you should know what you need for Windows SNMP-ing of HP server temperatures is:

1. Install SNMP (in Turn Windows features on/off)
2. Configure it

   1. services.msc->SNMP Service->Security tab->Add "public" community
   2. Add hostnames allowed to access the SNMP service (in the same tab)
3. Install HP Insight Management agents
4. Configure which agents to install (defaults)
5. Use SNMP to poll temperature e.g. 1.3.6.1.4.1.232.6.2.6.8.1.4 for sensor 1.

Answer (score 0):

If they're linux servers you can install the HP SNMP extensions and read that. I've not yet found a nice library to deal with the iLO.

Answer (score 0):

Dell provide a WMI interface as part of their OpenManage software so you can read data from their BMC using WMI from VBScript, Powershell or whatever. I've looked for something similar for the half a dozen HPs we have, but so far failed to find anything. Do any of you big HP users out there in Serverfault land know of any WMI software for the HPs?

If there is WMI software for the iLOs it is a very easy way to do what you want.

JR

Comment: I've never seen WMI used in conjunction with iLO. RDP, yes, but not WMI. The instrumentation drivers that expose iLO internals to the host operating system, and then using SNMP to poll the host OS for those internals, are as close as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just using HP SIM for this? it's what it's designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Which iLO? Original iLO, iLO2 or iLO3 (probably not given the date of the question)? If it's iLO2/3 they both support IPMI, either from the host OS or, to address your original intent over the network. Note that iLO2 needs the latest firmware (2.00 at time of writing) to fully support IPMI features over the LAN.

If it's original iLO then there's little/no support for IPMI sadly, however as others have said, you can use SNMP to query agents running on the host OS which query iLO/2/3 via "host channel" (this fails if the host OS is broken/rebooting). There's ssh, though the "DMTF SMASH" CLI syntax is a little odd. There's a way of pushing/pulling data in some XML format to/from iLO, but it again requires in-band access, i.e. not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As i know is not possible to get temperature via HPilo
at least on hpilo2 on Integrity
Is possible to get with hpux or linux using smh(linux/hpux) and crprop(hpux)
This at least on my old rx2600 server