# HP iLO get XML data

Tags: hp, xml, ilo, hp-proliant

I have a couple of HP servers with iLO interfaces. do you have any idea of how can i get status data of the server via an XML or something like that ?

**update:** i want to be able to get the server temperature via a script running on a linux machine in order to monitor our windows HP iLO servcers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/45508/automatic-get-server-temperature-via-hp-ilo) last month, and I provided instructions on where to go on HP's Web site to get the tools you needed. Here are exact links:

- You can get CPQLOCFG.EXE (as suggested by sleske) [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=4006&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-232d69dde5874c11b3ebc27ee3).
- You can get HPLOCFG.EXE (a similar tool) [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=4006&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-9994deee7e854c48934baeb2e5).
- You can get sample XML files and the Perl locfg.pl utility [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121516&prodNameId=3288134&swEnvOID=4006&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-a17bde2a8b0643c3b54a8d41f2).

I suggest also looking over the documentation on HP's Web site (at the link provided by sleske) as there is a wealth of information available.

Comment: These links no longer work :-(

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, bur someone addressed your question as if you were trying this from a windows box.
In Linux , (NOT WINDOWS...everyone) you can do this without an EXE tool. 
You need to use Net::ILO perl module. This will enable you to write a script that logs in to your ILO servers and interact with them.

1. download from http://search.cpan.org/~nlewis/Net-ILO-0.54/ (http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/N/NL/NLEWIS/Net-ILO-0.54.tar.gz)
2. after downloading :

   - tar -zxvf Net-ILO-0.54.tar.gz
   - cd  Net-ILO
   - perl Makefile.pl
   - make install

3) after compiled and installed, write a little perl script: (here is one that just prints out the temps:

**vim myscript.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# FILE:     /home/myuser/myscript.pl
# CREATED:  07:22:37 07/11/2011
# MODIFIED: 07:46:30 07/11/2011
use Net::ILO

my $ilo = Net::ILO->new(
#address of your system
    address     => '192.168.2.111',
    username    => 'Administrator',
    password    => 'yourpassword',
);

my $temperatures = $ilo->temperatures;

foreach my $sensor (@$temperatures) {

    print "    Name: ", $sensor->{name},     "\n";
    print "Location: ", $sensor->{location}, "\n";
    print "   Value: ", $sensor->{value},    "\n";
    print "    Unit: ", $sensor->{unit},     "\n";
    print " Caution: ", $sensor->{caution},  "\n";
    print "Critical: ", $sensor->{critical}, "\n";
    print "  Status: ", $sensor->{status},   "\n\n";

}
#---------end script
```

4) run the script - perl myscript.pl

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather vague. What status data do you want?
Please provide some examples.

That said, iLO offers scripting interfaces (via HP's tool CPQLOCFG.EXE, or via Perl). See the [HP documentation on iLO](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/ilobest-practice.html) for details.

Comment: what do i need CPQLOCFG.EXE for ? can't i just fire a perl script from a linux machine ?

Comment: where on earth can i find CPQLOCFG.EXE ? :-w

Comment: CPQLOCFG.EXE is HP's tool for managing iLO. It's available from HP, just googl it. As far as I understand, you do not really need it, you can also access the same functionality (and more) from perl, actually from any language, as the iLO is managed by sending XML files via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Again, see your earlier question, and my recent answer to it.

I wonder if you could merge this question into your previous one...

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to see if James' links were still working, and they seem to be - after selecting *"For products such as servers, storage, and networking, go to HP Support Center - Hewlett Packard Enterprise"* on a pop-up that announces that the impending split between HP Inc. and HP Enterprise will mean different support sites. Anyhow...

Utility aka CPQLOCFG.EXE can be found here http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=3288134&swItemId=MTX_232d69dde5874c11b3ebc27ee3&lang=en-us&cc=us

HP Lights-Out Online Configuration Utility for Linux aka hponcfg-1.9.0-3.noarch.rpm is available here http://h20565.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=3288134&swItemId=MTX_9994deee7e854c48934baeb2e5&lang=en-us&cc=us

HP Lights-Out XML PERL Scripting Sample for Linux is also found by following the link that James posted years ago - however, I am new to this community so I can only post two links per post.

The imminent HP company split may cause some disruption with links, so it may be worthwhile to get updated hpe.com links on your favorite topics if you are the bookmark using type.

Cheers,

Garg