# iLO from iPhone

Tags: hp-proliant, iphone, ilo

Does anyone know of an iPhone app that could interrogate [iLO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out) and present a summary of box's health information? A thin client that talks to another component that in turn talks to the iLO would work as well.

I have a lone HP Proliant server and installing Insight Manager just to be able to check the RAID status and power drain seems like a major overkill, and doing it through a browser is a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 3):

If you're managing a single server, there's no need to install Insight Manager. You can simply install the "ProLiant Support Pack" for the operating system and hardware of your choice and manage the system locally.

The drivers and [ProLiant Support Packs are available here](http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Nav?h_pagetype=s-002&h_lang=en&h_cc=us&h_product=241435&h_client=S-A-R163-1&h_page=hpcom&lang=en&cc=us). Choose your server model and OS.

Are you using Windows systems or Linux systems? Once the HP agents are installed, you can query the system health with command line utilities (`hpasmcli` or `hplog`) or connect to the server's local management homepage to see an overview of the system. That would be available at https://servername:2381.

```
[root@bootylicious ~]# hplog  -f
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS  REDUNDANT FAN SPEED 
 1  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Low    ( 38)
 2  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Low    ( 38)
 3  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Low    ( 38)
 4  Var. Speed   System Board    Normal     Yes     Low    ( 38)

[root@bootylicious ~]# hplog  -p
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS  REDUNDANT 
 1  Standard     Pwr. Supply Bay Normal     Yes      
 2  Standard     Pwr. Supply Bay Normal     Yes
```

OR

[image]

It's also possible to query the ILO via an SSH session, but you need to understand the ILO [command line syntax](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00294268/c00294268.pdf) to extract useful info. My preferred [ssh client for the iPhone and ipad is iSSH](http://www.zinger-soft.com/iSSH_features.html).

Also see the solutions at: [automatic get server temperature via HP iLO](https://serverfault.com/questions/45508/automatic-get-server-temperature-via-hp-ilo/45540#45540)

A thin client is another option, I suppose. You could just direct the thin client's browser to the System Management Homepage.

Answer (score 2):

HP has recently released iLO mobile apps for iPhone and Android.
[HP iLO Mobile App Information (old link)](http://www.hp.com/go/ilo/mobileapp)

[HPE iLO Remote Access](http://www.hpe.com/info/ilo#RemoteAccess)

RAID status is reflected in the system health of some iLO 3/4 systems.

The app can run RIBCL scripts, something like the `<GET_HEALTH_STATUS/>` command can give you what you want.