# Refresh a specific page in ilo 4

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, ilo, physical-environment

I use iLo 4 for my HP dl380 gen 8. I access iLo webpage using internet explorer 10. (Although I would gladly use another browser if anyone can recommend a better one for iLo access).

How can I refresh a specific page every X seconds? Hitting F5 just brings be back to the overview page.

I would like to refresh the temperature page every so often... it seems like the easiest way to monitor it during high loads. 
Thanks

Comment: SNMP is a better way to do that

Comment: I'm not familiar with SNMP, can you recommend a starting place to learn?

Comment: Try to start from here: http://serverfault.com/questions/45508/automatic-get-server-temperature-via-hp-ilo

Comment: Which OS are you running *on* the server?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 x64

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong...

First, I'd say it's not worth monitoring temperature fluctuations on a hyper-efficient server like an HP ProLiant Gen8. A [DL380p Gen8](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14212_na/14212_na.html) has **50** temperature sensors!! The only thing you need to control is your ambient temperature environment.

If you're just concerned about high-temperature conditions, the server can just email you. But if you *must* see this during high loads, you can.

You'll want to measure this from the OS directly, the System Management Homepage (at port 2381), through SNMP, through the ILO or even the ILO via SNMP.

HP servers have management agents available to the operating system (*I'll fill in details once you post the OS you're running*)...

*For instance, in Linux, using the HP Management Agents:*

```
# hplog -t 
ID     TYPE        LOCATION      STATUS    CURRENT  THRESHOLD 
 1  Basic Sensor Ambient         Normal    62F/ 17C 107F/ 42C 
 2  Basic Sensor CPU (1)         Normal   104F/ 40C 158F/ 70C 
 3  Basic Sensor CPU (2)         Normal   ---F/---C 158F/ 70C 
 4  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    77F/ 25C 188F/ 87C 
 5  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    75F/ 24C 188F/ 87C 
 6  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    78F/ 26C 188F/ 87C 
 7  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal    80F/ 27C 188F/ 87C 
 8  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
 9  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
10  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
11  Basic Sensor Memory Board    Normal   ---F/---C 188F/ 87C 
12  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    95F/ 35C 140F/ 60C 
13  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal   111F/ 44C 221F/105C 
14  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    71F/ 22C ---F/---C 
15  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    71F/ 22C ---F/---C 
16  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    73F/ 23C 167F/ 75C 
17  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    82F/ 28C 239F/115C 
18  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    71F/ 22C 239F/115C 
19  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    78F/ 26C 239F/115C 
20  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    80F/ 27C 239F/115C 
21  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    77F/ 25C 239F/115C 
22  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    78F/ 26C 239F/115C 
23  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    80F/ 27C 194F/ 90C 
24  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    71F/ 22C 194F/ 90C 
25  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal   152F/ 67C 212F/100C 
26  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    86F/ 30C 194F/ 90C 
27  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
28  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
29  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
30  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
31  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
32  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
33  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 212F/100C 
34  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    75F/ 24C 149F/ 65C 
35  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    77F/ 25C 150F/ 66C 
36  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    77F/ 25C 150F/ 66C 
37  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 149F/ 65C 
38  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 149F/ 65C 
39  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 149F/ 65C 
40  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal    82F/ 28C 150F/ 66C 
41  Basic Sensor I/O Zone        Normal   ---F/---C 150F/ 66C 
42  Basic Sensor Pwr. Supply Bay Normal    71F/ 22C 203F/ 95C 
43  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal   100F/ 38C 194F/ 90C 
44  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    80F/ 27C 176F/ 80C 
45  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    59F/ 15C 149F/ 65C 
46  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    82F/ 28C 167F/ 75C 
47  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    78F/ 26C 167F/ 75C 
48  Basic Sensor System Board    Normal    84F/ 29C 167F/ 75C 
49  Basic Sensor Chassis         Normal    80F/ 27C 167F/ 75C 
50  Basic Sensor Chassis         Normal    84F/ 29C 167F/ 75C
```

Or a view of the System Management Homepage:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. OS is Windows Server 2008. I understand that I can download "HP Insight Management Agents for Windows Server x64 Editions" but I don't really understand how to use SNMP.

Comment: You don't need SNMP. The HP management agents will allow you to query the system temperature from the command line or even the System Management Homepage. See above...